# Is the commit time in kaggle is the same as that of running the code?

Tags: kernel, kaggle

I have built a CNN in kaggle kernel which takes 4 hrs to get trained. Will the commit process also take the same amount of time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep! Committing will run all your code from top to bottom in a new environment. This is to help ensure reproducibility and that your final notebook output doesn't rely on manually running cells in a specific order.

Comment: Will the commit process also use GPU? The time taken to run is 4hrs using GPU . So if the commit process doesn't use GPU then i will have to wait for a lot of time

Comment: Yes, if your kernel using a GPU it should also use a GPU while commiting.